# Backgroundworker Errors

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

[image: Backgroundworker]I am trying to implement BackgroundWorker in my vb.net code. I understand you cannot update the UI from the background worker. Since when setting breakpoints in my code in the Backgroundworker.DoWork sub I would get 
Me.Accessibility.Object threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
Message "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FrmLoad' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

To try to understand why this was happening I copied the code EXACTLY from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2
and when setting a breakpoints again in the DoWork sub I get the same exception. I have tried several other microsoft code examples with the same issue. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace BackgroundWorkerSimple
    Public Partial Class Form1
        Inherits Form

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        End Sub

        Private Sub startAsyncButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            If backgroundWorker1.IsBusy <> True Then
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub cancelAsyncButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            If backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
            Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

            For i As Integer = 1 To 10

                If worker.CancellationPending = True Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    worker.ReportProgress(i * 10)
                End If
            Next
        End Sub

        Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
            resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%")
        End Sub

        Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
            If e.Cancelled = True Then
                resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!"
            ElseIf e.[Error] IsNot Nothing Then
                resultLabel.Text = "Error: " & e.[Error].Message
            Else
                resultLabel.Text = "Done!"
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
    End Namespace
```

It's not actually hindering the code from running, but I want to make sure that the thread is actually remaining safe.

Comment: I can't reproduce any exception with this code.  It happily stops wherever I place a debug stop.

Comment: It sounds like something is either corrupt in your project or on your system.  I'd try creating a new project and change as little as you can to try to get this code running.  If it still misbehaves, try the same thing on a different machine if you possibly can.  It might also help to get the stack trace for the exception, so you can see exactly where it's occurring.

Comment: I forgot to say earlier - the original code is in C#. I tried building a new project for bot the C# and .Net version - still the same issue. I can't right now try another computer as co-worker with license is away. I did try adding handlers as suggested by jmoreno and making sure the ProgressChanged Event handler was included as Michael Royston pointed out. Still no change. Just trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

That sample code is written in C#, and you apparently left out a function and it’s call:

```
    // Set up the BackgroundWorker object by 
    // attaching event handlers. 
    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += 
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += 
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += 
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }
```

While this can be rewritten using addhandler, the vbish way to do this is to add a handles clause to you method declaration.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitializeComponent()
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub startAsyncButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Start.Click
        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cancelAsyncButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Cancel.Click
        If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        'Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            If Not BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 10)
            Else
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%")
    End Sub

    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!"
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " & e.[Error].Message
        Else
            resultLabel.Text = "Done!"
        End If
    End Sub
```

The main thing it looked like you were missing was the Handles Event for the Background1.ProgressChanged